# Qt tablewidget editbox

Tags: qt, editbox

I created a tablewidget like this:

[image: Tablewidget]

I want to edit cell(0) value, (double click), but the edit box was too big and it covers cell(1):

[image: Tablewidget2]

How do I avoid the edit box covering the cell after it?

Comment: call `table->resizeColumnsToContents();` [resizeColumnsToContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#resizeColumnsToContents)

Comment: I add table->resizeColumnsToContents();  but the editbox still too big to cover the cell after it。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your own children QStyledItemDelegate and redefine QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor method.

Something like that:

```
QWidget * MyStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const 
{
    QWidget * editor = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
    editor->setWidth( 20 ); // Handle editor here.
    return editor;
}
```

Comment: QTableWidget *table;table->setItemDelegate(new  MyStyledItemDelegate); it really worked ！Thanks a lot！

Comment: another question，if I want setWidth（width）；I must pass a width param to MyStyleItemDelegate .   How to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: That common C++ issue. How to pass parameter on your class. Many and many ways, 
1) Via constructor of MyStyledItemDelegate() *table;table->setItemDelegate(new MyStyledItemDelegate(20)); You need  redefine constructor.
2) Via "setter" function
MyStyledItemDelegate * myDelegate = new MyStyledItemDelegate;
myDelegate->setEditorWidth(20); 
Need implement setEditorWidth()